# Не работает $watch AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, frontend

Есть такой код:

```
$scope.$watch(NgTimeManager.getTime(), function (time) {
                $scope.currentTime = time;
            });
```

Где:
**NgTimeManager.getTime()** - возвращает текущее время ( просто число, например: 1501589214000 ).
     **$scope.currentTime** - хочу в этой переменной иметь актуальное время.

Может я неправильно понимаю принцип работы $watch, по непонятным мне причинам переменная  currentTime не обновляется. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD переписал как в документации, не работает:

```
   $scope.$watch(NgTimeManager.getTime(), 
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue){
                console.log("Changed");
                $scope.currentTime =  newValue;
            }  
    });
```

Comment: это не watch Не работает, это ерунда написана. Посмотри какие параметры принимает `$watch` и посмотри что ты ему передаешь

Comment: вообще добавлять `watch` на постоянно изменяющееся значение - ошибка, просто сразу упадешь в infinit digest

Comment: _переписал как в документации, не работает_ - nope, это **НЕ** как в документации

Comment: какое решение лучше применить в моем случае?

Comment: я не знаю какую задачу ты хочешь решить и что такое _NgTimeManager_, но лучше всего именно его и использовать в том месте где надо получить время

Comment: Хочу чтобы со временем перемещался ползунок, для этого, в моем понимании, нужно обновлять значение времени.

Comment: Тогда воспользуйся советом использовать `$timeout` или `$interval` сервисы, они отрабатывают через указанные промежутки времени

Answer (score 0):

Просто запустите $interval и в его колбеке делайте то что вам надо.

```js
var app  = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("test", ['$interval','$scope',function($interval, $scope){
$interval(function(){$scope.time = new Date();}, 1000);
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body data-ng-app="app">
<div data-ng-controller="test">
<span data-ng-bind="time"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Но вообще то это идея плохая. Дело в том, что $interval каждый раз запускает digest который, в выполняет много другой работы. И запускать его лишний раз не стоит. Я бы, на вашем месте, реализовал этот ползунок на нативном js и обернул в директиву. Так вы получите и доступ к ползунку, и код будет чище, и сможете, если что, и с перформансом поиграться. Если вам не нужно ничего обновлять на вьюшке (что связано с ползунком) то от $intervala можно откзааться в пользу простого setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return NgTimeManager.getTime();}, 
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue){
            console.log("Changed");
            $scope.currentTime =  newValue;
        }  
});
```

Comment: не очень хороший совет, если `NgTimeManager.getTime()` при каждом вызове будет давать разные значения

Comment: @Grundy так разве не в этом смысл $watch? вызывается первая функция первый раз, сохраняется значение, вызывается первая функция второй раз, сравнивается с предыдущим, если значения разные, то вызываем колбэк в котором уже не обязательно проверять if (newValue !== oldValue).

Comment: _то вызываем колбэк_ и после этого запускаем digest опять, чтобы убедиться, что больше ничего не поменялось

Comment: @Grundy, это уже вопрос по архитектуре приложения. Изначальный вопрос был почему не работает $watch

Comment: Не приложения, а именно ангуляра